# How can I prove the existence of $X$ for the matrix equation $W^{*}XY = M$ for all $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

**Lemma:**

Suppose $W$ and $Y$ are matrices satisfying $ker(W)=0$ and $ker(Y)=0$. Then for every matrix $M$ there exists a solution $X$ to the equation

$$
W^*XY = M.
$$

**Attempt:**

Since $ker(W)=0$, we have a unique solution $x$ to the equation $Wx = b$ and the inverse $W^{-1}$ exists.

Similarly, the inverse $Y^{-1}$ exists. If $W^{-1}$ exists, we know $(W^*)^{-1}$ exists as well since $(WW^{-1})^* = I^*$.

Then, for any matrix $M$ (with appropriate dimension), there exists $X$ and $X = (W^*)^{-1}MY^{-1}$.

Is this proof sound? If not, how should I prove the given statement?

**Edit:**
There is no explicit mentioning of these matrices being square and so I think my approach is wrong. I am not sure how to prove it otherwise.

**Source**: page 209 from the textbook (link: http://read.pudn.com/downloads143/ebook/625700/A%20Course%20In%20Robust%20Control%20Theory.pdf)

Comment: Does it say anywhere that those are *square* matrices?

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't say these matrices being square. I guess then the existence of the inverse is invalid, right?

Comment: I guess it is invalid, indeed.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, thanks, is there an alternative way to prove this statement? This Lemma is from page 209 of the following text downloadable here: http://read.pudn.com/downloads143/ebook/625700/A%20Course%20In%20Robust%20Control%20Theory.pdf

Comment: There is a minor error. Since $W$ is only guaranteed to have a *left* inverse $W^{-1}$, you should have $W^{-1}W=I$ but not that $WW^{-1}=I$ (unless $W$ is square). So, it is $(W^{-1}W)^\ast$ but not $(WW^{-1})^\ast$ that is equal to $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A helper statement** (please check if you are already familiar with it, if not, I can fill in the gaps):

> Let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over any field. If $\ker(M)=0$, then there exists an $n\times m$ matrix $M'$ such that $M'M=I_n$.

Knowing $\ker(W)=0$ and $\ker Y=0$, this means that we can find such matrices $Y'$ for $Y$ (with $Y'Y=I$) and $W'$ for $W$ (with $W'W=I$). Note that $W^*(W')^*=(W'W)^*=I^*=I$. Now, for any matrix $M$ of an appropriate size, and look at this:

$$W^*((W')^*MY')Y=(W^*(W')^*)MY'Y=IMI=I$$

Thus we can take $X=(W')^*MY'$ as a solution of your equation $W^*XY=M$.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the helper statement $(3)$ but could you help me with the first two? Is the notation $M^{'}$ and $M^{''}$ referring to the pseudo-inverses?

Comment: I have now simplified the proof so that it only needs one of those. It is really a left or a right inverse of the matrix. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse#One-sided_inverse) I think pseudo-inverse is something a bit more sophisticated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse and I am not using it here. I use the symbol "prime" informally, not sure if there is an official symbol because taking a left or right inverse is not an operation - it is not unique.

Comment: For an $m\times n$ matrix, kernel being zero is equivalent to rank being $n$ (rank-nullity theorem: sum of rank and nullity is $n$) and so this is the full rank.

Comment: So, the kernel zero means having a full column rank (by the rank-nullity theorem) and the left inverse exists for matrices having a full column rank, right?

Comment: Sounds right. I personally like to look at matrices as linear maps. So if matrix $M$ has zero nullity, it means it maps linearly independent columns into linearly independent columns. Pick a base of the column space, map it using $M$, and what you get is linearly independent and can be then extended to a base of the "other" column space - then define the linear map mapping *that* base back into the chosen base (and maybe the added vectors to zero, or whatever you want!) and so the composition of the maps will be an identity and you can choose the left inverse as the matrix of that second map.

Comment: I see, so the left inverse that reverts the map $M$ exists because it is just a change of basis between two different sets of linearly independent columns..?

Comment: Sort of - the map of the first base is linearly independent - may not span the whole column space though (as possibly $m>n$), but it can always be *extended* to a base, and then you map back the first lot, and you map the extension to anything you like. Thus, if $m>n$ the "left inverse" will not be unique.

Comment: Oh, I think I see more clearly now! I will think more about this based on your comments, thank you very much!!